# Determine if Internet connection is available through wifi in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am developing an app that will be working offline also.

My scenario is this:
I have two WIFI devices in range to my mobile. Device1 has internet connection, where as the Device2 is like a WIFI-Hotspot, which sends only few data that my application will be using.

When I am connected to Device2 I start collecting the data and save in the mobile SQLite. When I change to Device1 and start have an internet connection I will be syncing the data to my server through an API call.

The case is when ever I have access to the internet I should be able to make that API call.

How do I achieve this?

I went through many articles and all I got is the connection status of the wifi device and not the internet connection.

**NOTE:** Please don't ask me to try this code:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);<br/>
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();<br/>
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Comment: Try creating a HTTP request and execute it. In response Code, you will get confirmation on Internet availability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Only thing u can do is

```
if(isNetworkAvailable}{
     if(isHostAvailable){
      //perform your communication
     }
}
```

//Check your server connectivity status

```
 private boolean isHostAvailable() {
    URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");// specify the url
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
     if(conn.getResponseCode().equalsIgnoreCase("200")){
          return true;
     }

    return false;
 }
```

//Check for device connectivity status

```
 private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
              = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

You will also need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just try to establish a TCP connection to a remote host:

```
public boolean hostAvailable(String host, int port) {
  try (Socket socket = new Socket()) {
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 2000);
    return true;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // Either we have a timeout or unreachable host or failed DNS lookup
    return false;
  }
}
```

And check it:

```
boolean online = hostAvailable("www.your-service.com", 80);
```

Comment: Ok I will try this.... But what I was expecting was is there a way to find the internet status without using a TCP or a HTTP connection??

Comment: there might be a framework that can handle this for you. But.. this will do nothing else than establishing a TCP connection...
Have you made some progress?